# Rails 3 - Many to Many - How would you do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, many-to-many

I have found lots of answers on StackOverflow but i'm kinda stuck on this one
I'll try first to describe with words what I have to do:

I have multiple applications, each application can have one or multiple profiles (one to many). 
I also have users, who have access to each applications through the different profiles. Each profile can have multiple users (many to many).
up to here no problem, i can get all profiles a user has been granted.

However, the difficulty here is that for each profile coming from an application, the user has a username, specific to each applications. When i see the details of a user, i want to see a list of all the profiles he's in together with the username he has been assigned for each application...

I'm sure there an easy way to do this with rails, as usual, but i can't seem to find it. How would you do this ?

Answer (score 2):

So to make sure I've got this: an Application can have many Profiles, and Users can have many Profiles.  So this isn't a simple many-to-many relationship between Application and User because the Profile is a first-class object.

Rails handles simple many-to-many relationships with the has_and_belongs_to_many (HABTM) association, declared on the models on both ends.  What's in the middle is unimportant and merely serves to join (relate) the two models.

Your case is more fun.  Your many-to-many is described in Rails as "has_many :through", and I think your case is a very good example of such a case.  In this case, Application and User each have many of the other through the Profile model.  Profile isn't there just to link the two, it holds username, and probably many other details of the User's relationship with his/her Applications.

Start with this [excellent guide which should show you how (and why) to choose has_many :through](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has_many-through-and-has_and_belongs_to_many) and how to get it all modeled and set up.  This is (as you suggest) one of the absolutely brilliant capabilities of Rails.

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thanks, this is the way to go indeed. i had tried that in the meantime, and it works. I was afraid it was not the right solution so i posted the question beforehand... i'm not a developer but i'm not that bad. However i'm having trouble with the edit form of the profile page. I want to be able to manage the users from there (add, remove and be able to specify which username they will have while adding a new user to a profile), i use fields_for but it seems to show only one blank field. I guess that's another question on a different matter, so i'll be back tomorrow fresh and early.